# Cannot read props type of 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im trying to pass simple properties from my child component  to the parent component . I can't for the life of me understand why I'm getting this error. My understanding of react is that you can declare props (i.e. this.props.text) in any function or class and then pass it to the parent.

Tickerbox.js (child)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
function Tickerbox(props) {
 return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <h1></h1>;
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>;
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}


export default Tickerbox;
```

App.js (parent)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Tickerbox from './TickerBox';


class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   day: 'monday',
   month: 'january',
   year: '1st',
 };
 }


render() {
     return (
       <div className="App">
       <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
       <div className="App-header">
         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         <h2>Hi</h2>
       </div>
       <div className="container">
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-3">day</div>
           <div className="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-3">month</div>
           <div className="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-3">year</div>
           <Tickerbox text="test"></Tickerbox>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
  }

  export default App;
```

Index.js (entry point)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tickerbox` it's a [`stateless`](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) component.

> Stateless components are declared as function

you are trying to access to `this.props.text` but you already have the props in the arguments `props`

Instead of use `this` use the `props` passed that are the actual props for that component

Tickerbox.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
function Tickerbox(props) {
 return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <h1></h1>;
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <h1>{props.text}</h1>;
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}


export default Tickerbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is we cannot access this.props.text in functional components. It should either be props.text or make it a class based component.

```
<h1>{props.text}</h1>;
```